# Why am I getting this error "Error: Query was empty"

Tags: php, mysql, forms, sql-update

I am trying to update my SQL database using a form through php, but i keep getting the error "Error: Query was empty".

```
<?php
$sql = "";
$con = mysql_connect("*******","*******");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("*******", $con);
mysql_query($sql, $con);


if (isset($_POST['STUDENT_FNAME'], $_POST['STUDENT_SNAME'],
$_POST['STUDENTNO'] ))
{ 

$sql="UPDATE STUDENT SET STUDENT_FNAME=('$_POST[STUDENT_FNAME]'),
STUDENT_SNAME=('$_POST[STUDENT_SNAME]')
WHERE STUDENTNO=
('$_POST[STUDENTNO]')";
}

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "1 record updated";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

It also won't update my table and I don't know what I've done wrong. All help will be much appreciated. I am new to this as you can probably tell!

Comment: remove `mysql_query($sql, $con);` line after DB selection line..and error will solve

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql Error: Query was empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19477827/mysql-error-query-was-empty)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `mysql_query($sql, $con)` query execution after db selection because `$sql` is empty,

Also put your  update sql execution in **IF conditions**, because if its not true than again $sql will be empty and you will get same error again,...

```
<?php
$sql = "";
$con = mysql_connect("*******","*******");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("*******", $con);
// mysql_query($sql, $con); // <-- remove this

if (isset($_POST['STUDENT_FNAME'], $_POST['STUDENT_SNAME'],
$_POST['STUDENTNO'] ))
{ 

$sql="UPDATE STUDENT SET STUDENT_FNAME=('$_POST[STUDENT_FNAME]'),
STUDENT_SNAME=('$_POST[STUDENT_SNAME]')
WHERE STUDENTNO=
('$_POST[STUDENTNO]')";

   if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
   {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
   }
   echo "1 record updated";
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Took out that line, still getting the error and data in the table still wont update. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your code first you are calling mysql_query($sql, $con); without any query in your $sql variable your $sql is blank ""

```
<?php
$sql = "";
$con = mysql_connect("*******","*******");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("*******", $con);


if (isset($_POST['STUDENT_FNAME'], $_POST['STUDENT_SNAME'],
$_POST['STUDENTNO'] ))
{ 

$sql="UPDATE STUDENT SET STUDENT_FNAME=('$_POST[STUDENT_FNAME]'),
STUDENT_SNAME=('$_POST[STUDENT_SNAME]')
WHERE STUDENTNO=
('$_POST[STUDENTNO]')";
}

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "1 record updated";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```